# Entity framework Cliente Venda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relacionamento

Estou com duvidas de como montar o relacionamento entre as classes Cliente e Venda, dando uma olhada no site da microsoft, fiquei com duvida se a classe deve ter a navegação para outra.

Quero o cliente tenha uma lista de Vendas e que Vendas tenha uma lista de ItemVenda.

Eu devo colocar uma propriedade para fazer a navegação de Venda para cliente? Pois eu vejo que a Venda não precisa guarda o cliente e sim o cliente guardar a venda dele.

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Venda> Vendas { get; }
}

public class Venda
{   
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; private set; }
    public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ItemVenda> ItemVenda { get; }
}


public class ItemVenda
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdProduto { get; set; }
    public int IdVenda { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public double Valor { get; set; }

    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; private set; }

}
```

Qual o jeito certo de configurar eles no ***EntityTypeConfiguration***

```
public class ConfiguracoesdeCliente : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
{
    public ConfiguracoesdeCliente()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.Id);

        Property(c => c.Nome)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150);

        Property(c => c.Sobrenome)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150);

        Property(c => c.Email)
            .IsRequired();

        //HasMany(p => p.Vendas);

        HasOptional(p => p.Vendas)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.Vendas);

    }
}

public class ConfiguracoesdeVenda : EntityTypeConfiguration<Venda>
{
    public ConfiguracoesdeVenda()
    {
        HasKey(v => v.Id);

        Property(v => v.Data)
            .IsRequired();

        HasMany(v => v.ItemVenda)
            .WithMany();
    }
}

public class ConfiguracoesdeItemVenda : EntityTypeConfiguration<ItemVenda>
{
    public ConfiguracoesdeItemVenda()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.Id);

        Property(p => p.VendaId)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.ProdutoId)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.Quantidade)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(p => p.Valor)
            .IsRequired();

        HasRequired(p => p.Venda)
            .WithMany(p => p.ItemVenda);

        HasRequired(p => p.Produto);

        //HasRequired(iv => iv.Venda);
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Entity Framework?

Comment: A versão é 6.0.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso depende muito de como você quer manipular seus dados.

No geral criamos uma lista no Cliente com suas vendas e um Cliente em venda para facilitar a navegação caso você esteja com a venda e queira buscar o cliente daquela venda.

Sua propriedade `public int ClienteId { get; set; }` poderia ser acompanhada com uma propriedade do próprio cliente escrito como `virtual` que faz com que o cliente já seja carregado dependendo das configurações do `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled` do EF.

Na [documentação do EF](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/) tem passo a passo de como você pode montar sua lógica de acordo com o que você precisar.

Comment: Então na classe Venda eu coloco o Cliente Cliente e o int CLienteId?

Comment: Se eu montar assim como vc falou, como eu configuro as 2 classes uma com a outra